# Criar divs em função das entradas da base de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, div

Bom dia,
Estou a desenvolver um site e gostava de criar uma div nova para cada entrada a base de dados apresentada em php. Preciso de fazer uma página com o mesmo princípio de um blog, o último conteúdo apresenta primeiro, mas para isso preciso que cada conteúdo tenha a sua própria div. Como posso fazer isto?
É a primeira vez que trabalho com conteúdos de uma base de dados para um site criado de raiz.

Comment: De que forma estás a consultar as entradas da base de dados??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se tiveres um array a ser devolvido da bd, basta fazeres um foreach dentro de um ficheiro php (a tua view), tipo:

```
<?php foreach ($registos as $registo) { ?>
//isto ja é html
<div>
    <?php echo $registo['texto']; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
 ...
```

Comment: Neste caso tenho várias informações na base de dados, incluindo um link para usar num iframe. Uso várias queries para esse efeito? E como utilizo o CSS nas diferentes divs? Uso a mesma class para todas?